# Prove the sum of integrals of function equals to the integrals of sum of functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(f_n)$ be a countable sequence of functions in $M^+(S,S)$, and let $g=\sum_nf_n$. Prove $\int gd\mu=\sum_n\int f_nd\mu$

Comment: Since each $f_i$ is nonnegative, the partial sums give an increasing sequence that converges to $g$. Then apply the monotone convergence theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $N \in \mathbb{N}$, define $g_N = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{N} f_i$. Then since each $f_i \geq 0$, we have $g_N \nearrow \sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}f_i$, so by the monotone convergence theorem,
\begin{align}
   \int \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} f_i d \mu &= \int \lim_{N \to \infty} g_N d \mu = \lim_{N \to \infty} \int g_N d \mu = \lim_{N \to \infty} \int \sum_{i=1}^{N} f_i d\mu \\
   &= \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{N} \int f_i d\mu = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \int f_i d\mu
  \end{align}

Comment: @dzzhang I mean that's a remark you could make, but in most standard analysis texts there is usually some theorem that says that the limit of a sequence of measurable functions is measurable and that sums are measurable functions. I was just being a little lazy and was assuming the reader would be be able to see that part right away for themselves.

Answer (score 1):

The monotone convergence theorem is the standard approach, just for giggles here is another way:

Note that $\sum_i f_i$ is the pointwise limit of a measureable function and hence is measureable.

Let $|\cdot|$ denote the counting measure on $\mathbb{N}$, then it is straightforward to check that the map $(x,i) \mapsto f_i(x)$ is measurable (and non negative) on $X \times \mathbb{N}$. Hence Tonelli shows that
$\sum_i \int f_i d \mu = \int ( \int f_i(x) d\mu(x)) d |\cdot|(i) = \int ( \int f_i(x) d |\cdot|(i) )  d\mu(x)  = \int (\sum_i f_i) d \mu$.